# How can I seek to an exact point in a Flash video without a Flash Media Server?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, video, flvplayback, seek

Is the Flash Video (or Flex VideoDisplay) component capable of seeking to an exact moment in a  video?

It seems to always 'snap' to keyframes (which is understandable). I'm just wondering if there are any mechanisms in the video classes for seeking to exact frames, ie it should do the translation from keyframe to specific frame in the background rather than having to actually play the video forward to the desired frame.

This is not a streaming file and has nothing to do with buffering. The player is just downloading a movie file from the web and playing it from memory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a streaming media server to jump to an exact moment in the video.

Otherwise you are stuck using progressive downloading, which will download every moment between the first one, and the moment you want to jump to.

You do not need to use Flash Media Server, though.  Red5 is an open source alternative.

I do not know specifics on the code needed to jump to a specific point, though.

Comment: I still wasn't clear enough: I'm specifically NOT concerned with jumping to frames in a video that isn't downloaded yet. For my purposes just assume the entire thing is already buffered into memory from a normal static file server. This is not about streaming or anything of the sort.

My concern is that, having the entire file in memory, I STILL cannot seek to EXACT moments: the player insists on snapping to nearby (or not so nearby) keyframes.

Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: I misunderstood the original question; sorry.  Unfortunately, I Do not have an answer for you.